# Phrygian vs freygish, what is the difference?

Tags: scales

What is the difference between Freygish and Phrygian mode? Are they related? Sometimes I see freygish explained as having a flat 5 and other times like it's just another name for the Phrygian mode.

Comment: Although the question is different, the answer addresses this topic.